# C++/Qt5 OpenGL функция glFrustum и glOrtho

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

Использую Qt5 для создания программы, использующей OpenGL.
Код:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    geese_size=30;
    wax=500; way=500; // начальный размер окна
    singling=false;
    geese_coord();
    setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer)); // Двойная буферизация
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(geese_coord()));
    timer->start(750);
}
void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::black); // Черный цвет фона
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // Буфер глубины
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

}
void MainWindow::resizeGL(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    //glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); // загружаем матрицу
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)nWidth, (GLint)nHeight);
    wax=nWidth;
    way=nHeight;
    glOrtho(0,wax,way,0,1,0); // подготавливаем плоскости для матрицы // Всё работает как надо
    //glFrustum(0,wax,way,0,1,0); //Если заменить предыдующую строчку этой, я увижу только черный экран
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // устанавливаем матрицу
    glLoadIdentity(); // загружаем матрицу
}
void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // чистим буфер изображения и буфер глубины
    //КодПрограммы
    glFlush();
    swapBuffers();
}
```

И собственно проблема - я не могу использовать glFrustum для правильного отображения 3D. Как мне это сделать? Может быть, нужно передать другие параметры glFrustum?

Comment: Похоже, у вас перепутаны местами два последних параметра, `nearVal` и `farVal`. Из-за этого пирамида видимости выворачивается наизнанку. И да, `nearVal` не может быть равным нулю — такова особенность процесса проецирования.

Comment: @Arhad пробывал всяко разно. Единственный результат, который я увидел был при glFrustum(0,wax,way,0,1.25,10); и это был текст в левом нижнем углу экрана, которой при нормальнух условиях отображался в левом верхнем углу экрана.

Comment: вопервых ненужно смешивать `QT` шные обёртки над `opengl` (`qgl...`) и нативные функции `gl...`, выберите что то одно, а если вы хотите в перспективной проекции используйте [`perspective`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#perspective) в `QT` есть всё необходимое \

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста изображения результат и что вы ожидаете. Это будет очень полезно для понимания проблемы.